# Too many redirects when using wp super cache

Tags: redirect, plugin-wp-supercache

For a couple of days i use the wp super cache plugin and it works quite well. I also updated to the latest version of wordpress which is currently Wordpress 3.4.1.

Whenever i update something in the posts. I can browse the front page of my blog but on the single page i get a too many redirects error. When i go to settings > permalinks and update the permalinks without any changes the blog is doing fine.

Is there some magic setting that avoid this behavior?

Comment: Do you have to update your permalinks every time you update a post to avoid this behavior? What's your permalink structure? Do you have any other plugins active?

Comment: What browser are you using? 

next - do you experience the same problem in other browsers.

Comment: also post your .htaccess, when you updated a post. and your .htaccess when resetting it. There will probably be a difference cause by the plugin.

Comment: Do you have "Extra homepage checks" enabled?

Comment: Why not switch to W3 Total Cache? Does that have the same error?

Comment: Please enable debugging in both WordPress and in WP Super Cache and share what you see in the error logs. In short, there is no setting in avoid this behaviour, from what I know.

Answer (score 1):

It's a cache problem. See if the cache directory is writable (it should be 755), try to empty it and try again.

Another cause might be the combination of CURL extension and enabled open_basedir. Check with your host.

Another solution might be to try the "Permalink Fix & Disable Canonical Redirects Pack" plugin - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/permalink-fix-disable-canonical-redirects-pack/